# Laravel - HTML is being removed from POST request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am probably missing something really obvious here so forgive me if that's the case.

I have a HTML Editor on a form and when I post the HTML to my controller the HTML is gone and therefore is not getting saved to the database.

Please see the image below.

[image]

Controller Function (this runs)

```
public function update(Request $request,Template $template){

  dd($request->all()); // code stops here 


    $template->subject = $request->input('subject');
    $template->body = clean($request->input('body'),'custom'); 
    $template->save();

    return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.template').' '.trans('messages.saved'), 'status' => 'success']);
}
```

Comment: Add your html, controller and the route used

Comment: Did you try to get the body by using `$request->body` or `$request->get('body')`?

Comment: I tried both David.

Comment: I found next method in [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_acceptsHtml). Maybe it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had some code that stripped all HTML from in the form of Middleware.

Hopefully this will help anyone learning/taking over someone's code. Look in the App\Http\kernal.php file to see if there is anything overriding your request data.